# Listview and php

Tags: php, android

I want to view all the appointment in my listview in Android.

I've created a function for it in PHP and call `getAppointment.php` as API.

When i do enter the first data, it appeared at my list view but when i enter the second data there is no second data on my list view.

Here my php code is : `getAppointment.php`

```
<?php 

define('DB_NAME','test');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);


//Creating sql query 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM appointment";

//getting result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//pushing result to an array 
$result = array();
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);
array_push($result,array(
        "idappointmnet"=>$row['idappointment'],
        "doctor"=>$row['doctor'],
        "mom"=>$row['mom'],
        "title"=>$row['title'],
        "place"=>$row['place'],
        "time"=>$row['time'],
        "date"=>$row['date']
    ));

//displaying in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I've tested this on postman.same thing happened there too.

Seems like something wrong with my PHP file. I don't know why this is happening. There's only one data can appear even though in the table there is two data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already fetch all records from DB table then why use `array_push` function

just simply fetch data and store into $result

```
$result = array();
// $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
```

Comment: glad to help you@user2908331